# Error blank page with gulp dist:serve

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp

```
vendor-bed50f88.js:31 Uncaught Error: 
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularMaterialAdmin due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularMaterialAdmin' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=angularMaterialAdmin
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you include "angularMaterialAdmin" within the module that is attempting to use it?

Such as...

```
angular.module('myMainModule', ['angularMaterialAdmin']);
```

If this module is in a separate file, is the reference to this file included in your main html page via a **script** element?

Comment: I tried to include angular.module('app', [ 'ngMaterial','angularMaterialAdmin','lfNgMdFileInput']); and not work , when I use gulp serve, the project works

Comment: Well, I'm assuming "gulp serve" ultimately launches a server to run the project locally?  Sounds like your project has dependencies needed to run within your "serve" task.  Other than the "serve" task in gulp, how are you attempting to run the application?